# From JSON file with function - to mysql - how to write a good code

Tags: php, json

I am rewritting function to get data from Json file to mysql. I have a bug in my code and I don't know where. If you can looking to function and tell me where do I do something wrong, I will be very happy.

json:

```
[{
"title":"Dumb Ways to Die 3 World Tour","gameType":"html5","description":"Play mini games featuring the characters from Dumb Ways to Die.\n\nDumb Ways to Die is a worldwide brand with over 300 million downloads on Apple App Store and Google Play combined.\n\nTest your reflexes in this challenging series of mini games, where a milisecond can make the difference between winning and losing.\n\nScore coins for each challenge, and use the to repair the once great town of Dumbville.",
"instructions":"Play mini games featuring the characters from Dumb Ways to Die.",
"url":"https://zxxcom/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e/",
"width":540,
"height":960,
"assetList":[{"name":"https://zxxcom/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e-512x340.jpeg"},{"name":"https://zxx.com/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e-512x512.jpeg"},{"name":"https://zxx.com/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e-512x384.jpeg"},{"name":"https://zxx.com/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e-1280x720.jpeg"},{"name":"https://zxx.com/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e-1280x550.jpeg"}],

"categoryList":[{"name":"Arcade"},{"name":"Sports"}],
"tagList":[{"name":"box2d"},{"name":"brain"},{"name":"brand"} ,{"name":"cute"},{"name":"endless"},{"name":"physi cs"},{"name":"simulation"},{"name":"cognitive"}],
"bundleList":[]},
```

code:

```
public function getParameterMap()
{
    return [
        'file' => 'url',
        'category' => ['categoryList']['name'],
        'thumbnail' => ['assetList']['name'],
        'tags' => ['tagList']['name'],
        'name' => 'title'
    ];
}

/**
* @param FeedGame $game
* @param $feedData
* @return mixed
*/
public function filterGame(FeedGame $game, $feedData)
{
    $game->setProviderId(substr(md5($feedData->name), 0, 5));
    $game->setCategory(array([($feedData->categoryList->name)]));
    $game->setThumbnail(array([($feedData->assetList->name)]));
    $name = $feedData->title;
    $description = $feedData->description;
    $game->setTags(array([($feedData->tagList->name)]));
}
```

After add data to mysql - in my base I see in category column – "Array". In tags column and thumbnail column, I see "Array" too.

In function filterGame - here I have something wrong, and I don't know, how to write it. Json file has array in array, and I don't know how to 
appeal to it.

Can you help me with this?

I want to have in mysql - thumbnail 512x512 and first category from categoryList (json), and all list of tags, with " , " after each tag.

Ps - sorry for my english - I learned it myself, and probably I do a lot of mistakes.

var_dump:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Dumb Ways to Die 3 World Tour',
    'gameType' => 'html5',
    'description' => 'Play mini games featuring the characters from Dumb Ways to Die.

Dumb Ways to Die is a worldwide brand with over 300 million downloads on Apple App Store and Google Play combined.

Test your reflexes in this challenging series of mini games, where a milisecond can make the difference between winning and losing.

Score coins for each challenge, and use the to repair the once great town of Dumbville.',
    'instructions' => 'Play mini games featuring the characters from Dumb Ways to Die.',
    'url' => 'https://zxx.com/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e/',
    'width' => 540,
    'height' => 960,
    'assetList' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'https://zxx.com/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e-512x340.jpeg',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'https://zxx.com/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e-512x512.jpeg',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'https://zxx.com/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e-512x384.jpeg',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'https://zxx.com/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e-1280x720.jpeg',
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'https://zxx.com/a91f360648334bc988222f1aff557c4e-1280x550.jpeg',
      ),
    ),
    'categoryList' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Arcade',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Sports',
      ),
    ),
    'tagList' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'box2d',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'brain',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'brand',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'cute',
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'endless',
      ),
      5 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'physics',
      ),
      6 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'simulation',
      ),
      7 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'cognitive',
      ),
    ),
    'bundleList' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'HeX PuzzleGuys',
    'gameType' => 'html5',
    'description' => 'Connect 4 hexagons of the same color, it\'s that simple!',
    'instructions' => 'Drag and drop pieces and connect at least 4 hexagons of the same color. When you get out of space, the game is over (luckily, you can always restart it!)',
    'url' => 'https://zxx.com/657afaed169b45b6a678637be1912c65/',
    'width' => 800,
    'height' => 600,
    'assetList' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'https://zxx.com/657afaed169b45b6a678637be1912c65-512x384.jpeg',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'https://zxx.com/657afaed169b45b6a678637be1912c65-512x512.jpeg',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'https://zxx.com/657afaed169b45b6a678637be1912c65-512x340.jpeg',
      ),
    ),
    'categoryList' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Puzzle',
      ),
    ),
    'tagList' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'hexagon',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'connect-4',
      ),
    ),
    'bundleList' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Your English  is fine, but your code is lacking. I don't see anywhere that you're parsing JSON in that code. Please see about creating a [mcve] for this problem.

Comment: edited question to better writting, what I want to have in my mysql.... I am not programist, but enthusiast, so on my websites usually I do all alone, but today I have this problem, and I don't know what to do. Probably first time :-) Arrays and json aren't my best side.

Comment: can you do var_dump of $feedData->tagList->name, can't really tell what that is

Comment: yes, I did it already